# /etc/environment is not read

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Very weird issue, the vars from /etc/environment are not set.

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
TEST="true"

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

$ echo $TEST

$
```

See **TEST is empty** and **/usr/local/games does not exist in the path**.

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, 3.19.0-25-generic

Comment: Have you tried `source /etc/environment` after your change?

Comment: Try: 

`export variable="value"`

Then login again or source the file

Comment: No, neither suggestion works.